# How to check a set of object is exist in another array object by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My array, stored in variable named `data`:

```
var data = [
  {
     "name": "username",
     "value": null,
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "name": "form.text"
     }
  },      
  {
     "name": "password",
     "value": null,
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "name": "form.text"
     }
  },
  {
     "name": "gender",
     "value": "other",
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "value_type": "string",
        "name": "form.select",
        "choices": [
           {
              "value": "male",
              "label": "Male"
           },
           {
              "value": "female",
              "label": "Female"
           },
           {
              "value": "other",
              "label": "Other"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "name": "country",
     "value": "3",
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "value_type": "string",
        "name": "form.select",
        "choices": [
           {
              "value": "1",
              "label": "Australia"
           },
           {
              "value": "2",
              "label": "USA"
           },
           {
              "value": "3",
              "label": "UK"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "name": "decision",
     "value": "not sure",
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "value_type": "string",
        "name": "form.text",
        "choices": [
           {
              "value": "yes",
              "label": "Yes"
           },
           {
              "value": "no",
              "label": "No"
           },
           {
              "value": "not sure",
              "label": "I am not sure"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "name": "hobby",
     "value": "['book', 'movie']",
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "value_type": "string",
        "name": "form.text",
        "choices": [
           {
              "value": "travel",
              "label": "Traveling"
           },
           {
              "value": "book",
              "label": "Reading"
           },
           {
              "value": "movie",
              "label": "Watching Movie"
           }
        ]
     }
  },
  {
     "name": "privacy",
     "value": null,
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "name": "form.text"
     }
  },
  {
     "name": "message",
     "value": null,
     "schema": {
        "version": 1,
        "name": "form.text"
     }
  }
]
```

My object, stored in variable named `formObj`:

```
var formObj = {


username: {
    value: null,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Username',
    placeholder: 'Enter username',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 1,
    additionalClass: 'user'
  },
  password: {
    value: null,
    type: 'password',
    label: 'Password',
    placeholder: 'enter password',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 2
  },
  country: {
    value: '3',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Where are you form?',
    //defaultText: 'Choose here',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 2,
    option: [{
        value: '1',
        label: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        value: '2',
        label: 'USA'
      },
      {
        value: '3',
        label: 'UK'
      }
    ]
  },
  gender: {
    value: 'female',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Gender',
    defaultText: null,
    position: 'right',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 1,
    option: [{
        value: 'male',
        label: 'Male'
      },
      {
        value: 'female',
        label: 'Female'
      },
      {
        value: 'other',
        label: 'Other',
        additionalAttr: 'disabled'
      }
    ]
  },
  decision: {
    value: 'not sure',
    type: 'radio',
    label: 'Have you enjoyed it?',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 1,
    option: [{
        value: 'yes',
        label: 'Yes',
        additionalAttr: 'disabled'
      },
      {
        value: 'no',
        label: 'No',
      },
      {
        value: 'not sure',
        label: 'I am not sure',
      }
    ]
  },
  message: {
    value: null,
    type: 'textarea',
    label: 'Message',
    placeholder: 'type your message',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 2,
  },
  vehicle: {
    value: 'car',
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Preferred vehicles',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 2,
    option: [{
        value: 'car',
        label: 'I like car'
      },
      {
        value: 'bike',
        label: 'I prefer bike'
      },
      {
        value: 'boat',
        label: 'Boat is my favorit'
      }
    ]
  },
  hobby: {
    value: ['book', 'movie'],
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Hobbies',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 3,
    option: [{
        value: 'travel',
        label: 'Traveling'
      },
      {
        value: 'book',
        label: 'Reading'
      },
      {
        value: 'movie',
        label: 'Watching movie'
      }
    ]
  },
  privacy: {
    value: null,
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Privacy',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 3,
    option: [{
        value: 'agree',
        label: 'I agree'
      }
    ]
  },
  email: {
    value: null,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Email',
    placeholder: 'Enter email',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 1,
    additionalAttr: 'disabled',
    additionalClass: 'emailbox custom'
  }
}
```

So, there are `8 objects` in the `data`(array) and `10 objects` in the `formObj`(object).

My target is matching the `name` from `data` with `formObj`, and create new object with the matched object only. All the `value` of the new object should come from the `data`(array). In short, create a `newObj` like/from `formObj`. `newObj` will not contain the object which are not in the `data`(array).

I have tried to write the concept here just, but don't understand how to go ahead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (data[i].name === formObj[key]) {
      newObj = formObj;   // take only those from formObj which exist in data
      newObj[option] = data[schema][choices];  // take the option from choices
      newObj[value] = data[value];  // take the value from value
   }
}
```

So, the `newObj` will be:

```
var newObj = {


username: {
    value: null,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Username',
    placeholder: 'Enter username',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 1,
    additionalClass: 'user'
  },
  password: {
    value: null,
    type: 'password',
    label: 'Password',
    placeholder: 'enter password',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 2
  },
  country: {
    value: '3',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Where are you form?',
    //defaultText: 'Choose here',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 2,
    option: [{
        value: '1',
        label: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        value: '2',
        label: 'USA'
      },
      {
        value: '3',
        label: 'UK'
      }
    ]
  },
  gender: {
    value: 'other',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Gender',
    defaultText: null,
    position: 'right',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 1,
    option: [{
        value: 'male',
        label: 'Male'
      },
      {
        value: 'female',
        label: 'Female'
      },
      {
        value: 'other',
        label: 'Other',
        additionalAttr: 'disabled'
      }
    ]
  },
  decision: {
    value: 'not sure',
    type: 'radio',
    label: 'Have you enjoyed it?',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 1,
    option: [{
        value: 'yes',
        label: 'Yes',
        additionalAttr: 'disabled'
      },
      {
        value: 'no',
        label: 'No',
      },
      {
        value: 'not sure',
        label: 'I am not sure',
      }
    ]
  },
  message: {
    value: null,
    type: 'textarea',
    label: 'Message',
    placeholder: 'type your message',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 2,
  },
  hobby: {
    value: ['book', 'movie'],
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Hobbies',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 3,
    option: [{
        value: 'travel',
        label: 'Traveling'
      },
      {
        value: 'book',
        label: 'Reading'
      },
      {
        value: 'movie',
        label: 'Watching movie'
      }
    ]
  },
  privacy: {
    value: null,
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Privacy',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 3,
    option: [{
        value: 'agree',
        label: 'I agree'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My working code:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/151f9r",
  method: "GET"
})
  .done(function(response) {
    var data = response.fieldset;
    console.log('.......................');
    console.log(data);
  })
  .fail(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
 });

var formObj = {
  username: {
    value: null,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Username',
    placeholder: 'Enter username',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 1,
    additionalClass: 'user'
  },
  password: {
    value: null,
    type: 'password',
    label: 'Password',
    placeholder: 'enter password',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 2
  },
  country: {
    value: '3',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Where are you form?',
    //defaultText: 'Choose here',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 2,
    option: [{
        value: '1',
        label: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        value: '2',
        label: 'USA'
      },
      {
        value: '3',
        label: 'UK'
      }
    ]
  },
  gender: {
    value: 'female',
    type: 'select',
    label: 'Gender',
    defaultText: null,
    position: 'right',
    block: 'firstRow',
    order: 1,
    option: [{
        value: 'male',
        label: 'Male'
      },
      {
        value: 'female',
        label: 'Female'
      },
      {
        value: 'other',
        label: 'Other',
        additionalAttr: 'disabled'
      }
    ]
  },
  decision: {
    value: 'not sure',
    type: 'radio',
    label: 'Have you enjoyed it?',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 1,
    option: [{
        value: 'yes',
        label: 'Yes',
        additionalAttr: 'disabled'
      },
      {
        value: 'no',
        label: 'No',
      },
      {
        value: 'not sure',
        label: 'I am not sure',
      }
    ]
  },
  message: {
    value: null,
    type: 'textarea',
    label: 'Message',
    placeholder: 'type your message',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 2,
  },
  vehicle: {
    value: 'car',
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Preferred vehicles',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 2,
    option: [{
        value: 'car',
        label: 'I like car'
      },
      {
        value: 'bike',
        label: 'I prefer bike'
      },
      {
        value: 'boat',
        label: 'Boat is my favorit'
      }
    ]
  },
  hobby: {
    value: ['book', 'movie'],
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Hobbies',
    position: 'left',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 3,
    option: [{
        value: 'travel',
        label: 'Traveling'
      },
      {
        value: 'book',
        label: 'Reading'
      },
      {
        value: 'movie',
        label: 'Watching movie'
      }
    ]
  },
  privacy: {
    value: null,
    type: 'checkbox',
    label: 'Privacy',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 3,
    option: [{
        value: 'agree',
        label: 'I agree'
      }
    ]
  },
  email: {
    value: null,
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Email',
    placeholder: 'Enter email',
    position: 'right',
    block: 'secondRow',
    order: 1,
    additionalAttr: 'disabled',
    additionalClass: 'emailbox custom'
  }
}

console.log(formObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the `data` array.Check if the name exist as the key on `formObj` using `hasOwnProperty`. If it exist use spread syntax to shallow copy the object and overide the value property.

```js
var data = [{"name":"username","value":null},{"name":"password","value":null},{"name":"gender","value":"other"},{"name":"country","value":"3"},{"name":"decision","value":"not sure"},{"name":"hobby","value":[]},{"name":"privacy","value":null},{"name":"message","value":null}]
var formObj = {"username":{"value":null,"type":"text","label":"Username","placeholder":"Enter username","position":"left"},"password":{"value":null,"type":"password","label":"Password","placeholder":"enter password","position":"left"},"gender":{"value":"female","type":"select","label":"Gender","defaultText":null,"position":"right"},"country":{"value":"3","type":"select","label":"Where are you form?","position":"right","block":"firstRow"},"decision":{"value":"not sure","type":"radio","label":"Have you enjoyed it?","position":"left","block":"secondRow"},"email":{"value":null,"type":"text","label":"Email","placeholder":"Enter email","position":"right"},"hobby":{"value":[null,null],"type":"checkbox","label":"Hobbies","position":"left","block":"secondRow"},"privacy":{"value":"","type":"checkbox","label":"Privacy","position":"right","block":"secondRow"},"message":{"value":"","type":"textarea","label":"Message","placeholder":"type your message","position":"right"},"vehicle":{"value":"car","type":"checkbox","label":"Preferred vehicles","position":"left","block":"secondRow"}}

var newObj = data.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (formObj.hasOwnProperty(v.name)) c[v.name] = {...formObj[v.name],value: v.value};
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Actually, `option[]` should be in `gender`, `country`, `decision`, `hobby`, `privacy` in `newObj` like `formObj`. That's why, I asked for creating `newObj` from `formObj`.

Comment: Your `formObj` on your original post has none of those properties. The object is from  `formObj` so if your `formObj` has those, it will be shallowed copy to the new `newObj`

Comment: sorry, I used those at the working code snippet. To keep the post size small, I didn't show them in the post. But, it was in the code snippet. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I tried the solution with the updated `data` and `formObj` and it seems to be working.

Comment: can you please explain what did you mean by c & v in the parameter?

Comment: The `c` is carried value or the accumulator. The `v` is the current array value/element.

Comment: You can check doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to break this task into three steps:

1. Extract the key/value entries of `formObj` into an array via the `Object.entries()` method
2. Filter the extracted key/value pairs from `formObj` to remove entries that don't have matching `name` in `data` array
3. Construct `newObj` via the `reduce()` method, to reduce the array of filtered key/value entries into a single object

This can be implemented by the following:

```js
var data = [{"name":"username","value":null},{"name":"password","value":null},{"name":"gender","value":"other"},{"name":"country","value":"3"},{"name":"decision","value":"not sure"},{"name":"hobby","value":[]},{"name":"privacy","value":null},{"name":"message","value":null}]
var formObj = {"username":{"value":null,"type":"text","label":"Username","placeholder":"Enter username","position":"left"},"password":{"value":null,"type":"password","label":"Password","placeholder":"enter password","position":"left"},"gender":{"value":"female","type":"select","label":"Gender","defaultText":null,"position":"right"},"country":{"value":"3","type":"select","label":"Where are you form?","position":"right","block":"firstRow"},"decision":{"value":"not sure","type":"radio","label":"Have you enjoyed it?","position":"left","block":"secondRow"},"email":{"value":null,"type":"text","label":"Email","placeholder":"Enter email","position":"right"},"hobby":{"value":[null,null],"type":"checkbox","label":"Hobbies","position":"left","block":"secondRow"},"privacy":{"value":"","type":"checkbox","label":"Privacy","position":"right","block":"secondRow"},"message":{"value":"","type":"textarea","label":"Message","placeholder":"type your message","position":"right"},"vehicle":{"value":"car","type":"checkbox","label":"Preferred vehicles","position":"left","block":"secondRow"}}

/* Extract key value entries from input object */
const keyValues = Object.entries(formObj)

/* Filter input object entries by existence of 
name matching key from data array */
const filteredKeyValues = keyValues.filter(([key, value]) => {
  return data.findIndex(({ name }) => name === key) !== -1;
});

/* Construct newObj object from filtered key value entries */
const newObj = filteredKeyValues.reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
  return { [key] : value, ...result };
}, {});
  
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. Actually, `option[]` should be in `gender`, `country`, `decision`, `hobby`, `privacy` in `newObj` like `formObj`.

Comment: I wrote full format in the code snippet. But, to keep the post size small, I didn't show them all at the text of the post. Sorry, for the confusion.

Comment: You're welcome - if the `object` array is in any value(s) of `formObj` then they should be copied through to `newObj` in the answer above. Does that help?